# Java: Error in calling another class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

// I managed to fix it, there was a completely unrelated error which wasn't given as an error, I deleted the code and now it works. Thanks for your time.

Hi, 
I created a Java program in Eclipse which worked fine, despite 1 error in my class, I'll show it in my code later. I have a Folder class which uses the Document class and creates a new one when a button in the menu is clicked. This used to work fine, but yesterday something weird happened with Eclipse and my pc and now it won't work, eventhough the code didn't change a bit.

If you need extra information or if I the question isn't correct, just say it. This is one of my first questions. I'm still learning.

//Edit
When I hover over the error in Document.java (public class Document extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener) it says:

```
The type Document must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
```

But when I make it abstract, it only creates more errors.

Folder.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Font.*;
import java.util.*;

//Main screen

public class Folder extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:/users/jeroe_000/pictures/flogo.png");
    private JFrame JFrame = new JFrame();
    private JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu men = new JMenu("Window");
    private JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New window");
    private JMenuItem closeItem = new JMenuItem("Close all windows");
    private JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Close");
    public JPanel startscreen = new JPanel();

    public boolean opened = false;

    public String programName = "Sitebucket Office";


    private JDesktopPane bord = new JDesktopPane();
    private int n; //number of internal windows 



    private Folder() {      
        setContentPane(bord);
        setJMenuBar(mb);
        mb.add(men);
        men.add(newItem); men.add(closeItem); men.addSeparator(); men.add(exit);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        //connect listener to the menu alternatives
        newItem.addActionListener(this);
        closeItem.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        setTitle("Sitebucket Office");
        setSize(900, 700);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        startscreen.setVisible(true);
        JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Welcome to Sitebucket Office");
        contentPane.add(startscreen);
        startscreen.add(welcome, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        //Opmaak

        bord.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        bord.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165, 70 ));
        bord.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));

        mb.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));
        mb.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));

        men.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));
        men.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        men.setFont(new Font("Oxygen Light", Font.PLAIN,  20));

        newItem.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));
        newItem.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        newItem.setFont(new Font("Oxygen Light", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        closeItem.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));
        closeItem.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        closeItem.setFont(new Font("Oxygen Light", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        exit.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));
        exit.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        exit.setFont(new Font("Oxygen Light", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == newItem) {
            Document f = new  Document("Document " + (n+1));
            bord.add(f);
            int x = Math.min(30*n, bord.getWidth() - f.getWidth());
            int y = Math.min(30*n, bord.getHeight() - f.getHeight());
            f.setLocation(x, y);

            f.moveToFront();
            n++;
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == closeItem) {
            JInternalFrame[] a = bord.getAllFrames();
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                a[i].dispose();
            n = 0;
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == exit){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String arg[]) {
        new Folder();
    }

}
```

Document.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Font.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Document extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener{    //HERE'S THE ERROR
    public JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10,60);
    public JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    public String currentFile = "Untitled";
    public boolean changed = false;
    public JTextField fontField;






    public Document(String title){

        //Window
        super(title, true, true, true, true);
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);


        fontField = new JTextField(5);

        fontField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = fontField.getText();
                try {
                    float fontSize = Float.parseFloat(text);
                    int textSize = Math.round(fontSize);
                    Font textFont = fontField.getFont();
                    textFont = textFont.deriveFont(fontSize);
                    area.setFont(textFont);
                    revalidate();
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        //Textarea
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);//Scrollable textarea
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Adding the textarea


        //Menubar
        JMenuBar textMb = new JMenuBar(); 
        setJMenuBar(textMb);
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu layoutMenu = new JMenu("Layout");
        JMenu fontMenu = new JMenu("Font");
        JMenu fontSizeMenu = new JMenu("Fontsize");
        JMenu menuSizeMenu = new JMenu("Menu-fontsize");
        JMenu textSizeMenu = new JMenu("Text-fontsize");

        JMenu betaMenu = new JMenu("Bèta functions");

        JLabel fontSizeText = new JLabel("Enter the fontsize down here");
        textMb.add(fileMenu); textMb.add(editMenu); textMb.add(layoutMenu);

        //Adding buttons to filemenu -> menubar
        fileMenu.add(open); fileMenu.add(save); fileMenu.add(saveAs);

        //Adding buttons to editmenu -> menubar
        editMenu.add(cut); editMenu.add(copy); editMenu.add(paste); editMenu.add(selectAll);
        editMenu.getItem(0).setText("Cut");
        editMenu.getItem(1).setText("Copy");
        editMenu.getItem(2).setText("Paste");
        editMenu.getItem(3).setText("Select all");

        //Adding buttons to layoutmenu ->menubar
        layoutMenu.add(fontMenu); layoutMenu.add(fontSizeMenu);

        //Fontmenu
        fontMenu.add(arial); fontMenu.add(opensans); fontMenu.add(oxygenlight); fontMenu.add(segoeuilight); fontMenu.add(timesnewroman);

        //Fontsizemenu
        fontSizeMenu.add(fontSizeText); fontSizeMenu.add(fontField);


        //Layout
        textMb.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));

        fileMenu.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));
        fileMenu.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        fileMenu.setFont(new Font("Oxygen Light", Font.PLAIN, 16));

        editMenu.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));
        editMenu.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        editMenu.setFont(new Font("Oxygen Light", Font.PLAIN, 16));

        layoutMenu.setBackground(new Color(58, 119, 165));
        layoutMenu.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        layoutMenu.setFont(new Font("Oxygen Light", Font.PLAIN, 16));




        //Default stuff
        save.setEnabled(false);
        saveAs.setEnabled(false);
        setVisible(true);

        area.addKeyListener(kl); //To be able to write
        setTitle(currentFile); //Screentitle
    }





        private KeyListener kl = new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                changed = true;
                save.setEnabled(true);
                saveAs.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };


        String text2 = fontField.getText();
        float fontSize2 = Float.parseFloat(text2);
        int textSize2 = Math.round(fontSize2);



        Action arial = new AbstractAction("Arial") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                area.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, textSize2));
                revalidate();
            }
        };

        Action opensans = new AbstractAction("Open Sans") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                area.setFont(new Font("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN, textSize2));
            }
        };

        Action oxygenlight = new AbstractAction("Oxygen Light") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                area.setFont(new Font("Oxygen Light", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            }
        };

        Action segoeuilight = new AbstractAction("Segoe UI Light") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                area.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Light", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            }
        };

        Action timesnewroman = new AbstractAction("Times New Roman") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                area.setFont(new Font("Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            }
        };

        //Default stuff for new documents
        Action newFile = new AbstractAction("New") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveOld();
                area.setText("");
                currentFile = "Untitled";
                setTitle(currentFile);
                changed = false;
                save.setEnabled(false);
                saveAs.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };

        //Default stuff for opening documents
        Action open = new AbstractAction("Open ...") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveOld();
                if (dialog.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    readFile(dialog.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                }
                saveAs.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };

        //Default stuff for saving documents
        Action save = new AbstractAction("Save") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!currentFile.equals("Naamloos")){
                    saveFile(currentFile);
                }
                else {
                    saveFileAs();
                }

            }
        };

        //Default stuff for saving as documents
        Action saveAs = new AbstractAction("Save as ...") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveFileAs();
            }
        };

        //Default stuff for closing documents
        Action exit = new AbstractAction("Close") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(changed == true){ 
                    saveFileAs();
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                else{
                    saveOld();
                    System.exit(0);                 
                }
            }
        };

        ActionMap m = area.getActionMap();
        Action cut = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.cutAction);
        Action copy = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.copyAction);
        Action paste = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction);
        Action selectAll = m.get(DefaultEditorKit.selectAllAction);

        private void saveFileAs() {
            if (dialog.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                saveFile(dialog.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        private void saveOld() {
            if (changed) {
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,  currentFile + "save?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    saveFile(currentFile);
                }
            }
        }

        private void readFile(String fileName) {
            try {
                FileReader r = new FileReader(fileName);
                area.read(r, null);
                r.close();
                currentFile = fileName;
                setTitle(currentFile);
                changed = false;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, fileName + "can't be found");
            }
        }

        private void saveFile(String fileName) {
            try {
                FileWriter w = new FileWriter(fileName);
                area.write(w);
                w.close();
                currentFile = fileName;
                setTitle(currentFile);
                changed = false;
                save.setEnabled(false);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```

IntPaintWindow.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class IntPaintWindow extends JInternalFrame{
    public IntPaintWindow(String title){
        super(title, true, true, true, true);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot instantiate the type Document

    at Folder.actionPerformed(Folder.java:84)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know this is a lot of information, but I'd really appreciate it if you guys could help me fix this error.

Kind regards, Jeroen

Comment: try changing the the name of Document class

Comment: "Unresolved compilation problem" means that your source files and compiled class files are out of sync. Delete all the compiled class files and re-compile all your source files.

Comment: Maybe it thinks you meant java.swing.text.Document, instead of your class called Document.

Comment: Changing the name doesn't work.

Comment: @iJeroen then what is the problem click on the symbol on the right side of that line and then click `Add unimlemented methods`

Comment: what @Jesper said, try to do a "clean and build"

Comment: When I do a clean build, about everything gives an error

Comment: The errors you get when you do a clean build are the actual errors you need to solve.